# Как убрать активный класс с элемента при клике, если он уже имеет этот класс?

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается найти ошибку, почему класс не убирается при клике на элемент который уже имеет этот класс
html:

```
       <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4>panel 1</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4>panel 2</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>2 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
function ready() {
    var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; panels.length > i; i++) {
        panels[i].onclick = function() {
            for (i = 0; panels.length > i; i++) {
                panels[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
                this.classList.remove("active")
            } else {
                this.classList.add("active")
            }
        };
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: действительно, спасибо, потратил мин 30 из-за этого )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без циклов внутри обработчика.

Функция [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает *живую* коллекцию. Таким образом получив один раз коллекцию для класса *active*

```
var actives = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
```

В ней всегда будут актуальные данные. И так как подразумевается только один активный элемент он будет доступен по индексу 0.

Теперь в обработчике достаточно проверить, что был предыдущий активный элемент и убрать с него класс *active*

```
var currentActive = actives[0];
if (currentActive)
  currentActive.classList.remove("active");
```

И если щелкнули не по активному элементу - нужно добавить этому элементу класс *active*

```
if (currentActive !== this)
  this.classList.add("active");
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
var actives = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
for (i = 0; panels.length > i; i++) {
  panels[i].onclick = function() {
    var currentActive = actives[0];
    if (currentActive)
      currentActive.classList.remove("active");

    if (currentActive !== this)
      this.classList.add("active");
  };
}
```

```css
.active {
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>panel 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>panel 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>2 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

в цикле пропускать элемент, на который щелкнули

т.e.

```
for (i = 0; panels.length > i; i++) {
  if (panels[i] != this)
    panels[i].classList.remove("active");
}
```

Comment: чтото не так, если мы кликаем на панель, то эта должна открыться а остальные панели закрыться, но если на нее же кликнуть, то она должна закрыться

Comment: @DimaVleskov с помощью кнопки "Фрагмент кода на ..." создайте, пожалуйста, в Вашем вопросе работающий пример, в котором "что-то не так"