# Изменение стиля

Tags: javascript, css

Почему после нажатия пропадает стиль для :hover ?
 - Как этого избежать ?
Желательно объяснить как для "незнайки" ;)

```js
function bomba() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
}

function bomba2() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
}

function bomba3() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

.bomba li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.bomba li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul  class="bomba">
   <li id="1_1" onclick="bomba()">Кукушка</li>
   <li id="1_2" onclick="bomba2()">Воробей</li>
   <li id="1_3" onclick="bomba3()">Грач</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: потому что inline стиль, который устанавливается в строках _document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom=..._ приоритетнее, и просто перебивает стиль описанный для :hover

Comment: @Grundy, я почти уже ответил, а Вы меня перебили! :)

Comment: лучше не использовать inline стили, а добавлять/убирать класс, это позволит избежать проблемы с приоритетом и сократит код. Пример можно посмотреть в [похожем вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626959/186999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике вы назначаете стиль inline:

```
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
```

inline означает внутри тега, те. так:

```
<li ... style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(221, 0, 68);">...</li>
```

Стиль inline имеет всегда больший приоритет по сравнению с обычными стилями. За исключением метки `!important`:

```js
function bomba() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
}

function bomba2() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
}

function bomba3() {
document.getElementById('1_1').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_2').style.borderBottom='2px solid #fff';
document.getElementById('1_3').style.borderBottom='2px solid #d04';
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

.bomba li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.bomba li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray !important; /*Здесь теперь будет больший приоритет*/
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul  class="bomba">
   <li id="1_1" onclick="bomba()">Кукушка</li>
   <li id="1_2" onclick="bomba2()">Воробей</li>
   <li id="1_3" onclick="bomba3()">Грач</li>
</ul>
```

Однако, не рекомендую использовать `!important` без крайней необходимости. Все что нужно сделать - назначить класс при клике:

```
document.getElementById("1_1").className = "active";
```

и этот класс кастомизировать обычными стилями:

```
.bomba li.active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```js
function bomba() {
document.getElementById("1_1").className = "active";
document.getElementById("1_2").className = "";
document.getElementById("1_3").className = "";
}

function bomba2() {
document.getElementById("1_1").className = "";
document.getElementById("1_2").className = "active";
document.getElementById("1_3").className = "";
}

function bomba3() {
document.getElementById("1_1").className = "";
document.getElementById("1_2").className = "";
document.getElementById("1_3").className = "active";
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

.bomba li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.bomba li.active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.bomba li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray; 
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.bomba li.active:hover{/*стиль для активного и подсвеченного элемента*/
    border-bottom: 4px solid red; 
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul  class="bomba">
   <li id="1_1" onclick="bomba()">Кукушка</li>
   <li id="1_2" onclick="bomba2()">Воробей</li>
   <li id="1_3" onclick="bomba3()">Грач</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо , не знал такие нюансы.

Comment: @Vipz, вместо спасибо, у нас используется репутация. И, если ответ Вас устроил, примите его (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Спасибо , оставил.
- До этого думал "жаль нет репутации" , в не привычном месте находится.