# Изменить цвет элемента по клику

Tags: javascript, css, функции

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на td изменялся его цвет, но при клике на другой td цвет предыдущего исчезал.

```js
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(let i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
  let td_ = td[i];
  td_.addEventListener('click', function () {
    td_.setAttribute('class','active');
  });
}
```

```css
td{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
td.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id = 'kappa'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626959/256824

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    var el = document.querySelector('.active')
    el && el.classList.remove('active')
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #DDD;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr>
  <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr>
  <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
class Changer {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    const cell = e.target.closest('td');

    if (!cell) return;

    this.unsetActiveCell();
    this.setActiveCell(cell);
  }

  setActiveCell(cell) {
    cell.classList.add('active');
  }

  unsetActiveCell() {
    [...this.node.querySelectorAll('.active')]
    .forEach(td => td.classList.remove('active'));
  }
}

new Changer(document.querySelector('#kappa'));
```

```css
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="kappa">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Еще красивее было бы, если бы вы как ВебКомпонент бы создали эту таблицу `class Changer extends HTMLTableElement`.

Answer (score 3):

Разношерстные ответы, поэтому безумства ради :)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#kappa tbody td')
  .forEach((item, index) => {
    item.setAttribute('tabindex', index + 1)
  })
```

```css
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.active,
td:focus {
  background-color: #08c;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="kappa">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Использована простая логика: При каждом клике перебираем все существующие td и везде убираем класс 'active' (хоть он и присутсвтует только у одного). После чего добавляем этот класс на текущий кликнутый, `this`

```js
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
// или = document.querySelectorAll('#kappa td');

for(let i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(let u = 0; u < td.length; u++){
      td[u].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

```css
td{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
td.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id = 'kappa'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Можно еще при клике сохранять куда-нибудь номер кликнутой кнопки. И дальше без лишнего перебора, скрывать предыдущий:

```js
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
let prev = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    td[prev].classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
    prev = i; /* в конце каждого клика в prev сохраняем номер кликнутой кнопки.
    А вначале следующего круга этот же номер используется, чтобы удалить класс */
  });
}
```

```css
td{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
td.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id = 'kappa'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

просто перед активацией отключает все другие td

```
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(let i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
  let td_ = td[i];
  td_.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //отключает все другие td
    for (let i of td) {
      i.setAttribute('class','');
    }
    td_.setAttribute('class','active');
  });
}
```

или запоминает номер активного td, и при активации другого td отключает его

```
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
//номер активного td (-1 значит никакой)
let active_i = -1;
for(let i = 0; i<td.length; i++){
  let td_ = td[i];
  td_.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //если какой-то другой td активен - отключить его
    if(active_i>=0&&active_i!=i){ //1 - проверить активен ли какой-то td, 2 - защита если хотите сделать анимацию
      td[active_i].setAttribute('class','');
    }
    td_.setAttribute('class','active');
    //задаёт номер активного td
    active_i = i;
  });
}
```