# У объекта 2 состояния, как сделать чтобы при одном нажатии, эти состояния менялись?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Я новичок во Fronted разработке.
Нужно создать Circle, у него два состояния: 1(красный цвет) и 0(черный цвет).
Когда я делаю клик по нему один раз, у него должно смениться состояние на 1(цвет тоже), еще раз  на состояние 2(черный цвет) и тд. И таких кругов у меня 100шт.
Не знаю как реализовать, использую JS+JQuery, пример кода:

```
let elem = {
     flag: 1

};

function flag_1(elem)
{
      var arr = [];

      document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ' ';
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
          if(document.getElementById((elem).id) == document.getElementById((arr[i]).id)) {
              $(arr[i]).css('background-color', 'black');
              arr.splice(i, 1);
          }
          context = document.getElementById((arr[i]).id).innerText;
          document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += ' ' + context;

            }
      elem.flag=2; 
}
function flag_2(elem)
{
      context = document.getElementById((elem).id).innerText;
      document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ' ';
      arr.push(elem);
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          $(arr[i]).css('background-color', 'blue');
          context = document.getElementById((arr[i]).id).innerText;
          document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += ' ' + context;
              }

         elem.flag=1;
}

 $( ".content_SdBaG6WP" ).click(function()  {
      switch(elem.flag) {
        case 2:  // if (x === 'value1')
                    flag_2(this);
          alert(elem.flag);
          break;
        case 1:  // if (x === 'value2')
                    flag_1(this);
                    alert(elem.flag);
          break;
      }
});
```

Отрисовка самих кругов в HTML, с использованием JS:

```
document.writeln('<button id="#content_SdBaG6WP' + k +'" class="content_SdBaG6WP" type="button" style="transform: translateX('+ x +'px) translateY('+ y +'px) rotateX(-45deg);">'+ k +'</div>');
```

Вот сами круги:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идея просто создать Класс(потому что круги у меня будут разных цветов), и присвоить эти свойства класса каждому кругу, но не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: не понял вот этой фразы - `у него должно смениться состояние на 1(цвет тоже)`, как понять  `цвет тоже`, помимо цвета еще какое то состояние?

Comment: Я просто уточнила, что должен поменяться цвет.

Comment: При клике на каждый элемент, в зависимости от цвета элемента,  должен меняться цвет элемента и все?

Comment: Может помогут ответы в этих вопросах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626959/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/985520/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял автора вопроса, то тут все проще, чем кажется автору

```js
let text = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.textContent = text[i];

  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getComputedStyle(s)['background-color'] === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' ?
      s.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' :
      s.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2.3;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Отлично, это то что мне нужно!
Но у меня есть ряд вопросов!
1)Как я смогу расположить эти круги в ряд 10х10, как это показано на рисунке выше?

Comment: По идее, у каждого круга есть своя цена, как я могу ее хранить?
В круге или создавать отдельный массив, чтобы хранить цену каждого круга?

Comment: Что касается расположения, это отдельный вопрос.... Вариантов куча...  А вот,  что касается значений элементов, то на мой взгляд лучше массив... Не могу пример привести , я с планшета... может быть чуть позже...

Comment: Спасибо!
Есть еще вопрос!
Допустим, я хочу сделать 1 ряд кругов синего цвета, а 2 ряд зеленого и тп.
Прочитала документацию...Что-то сделала, но не получается(
Я использовала твой пример, но создала несколько массивов, потому что цветов у меня несколько, и решила forEach пробежаться и прокрасить

Comment: ``
[...document.querySelectorAll('content_SdBaG6WP')].forEach((s, i, mesto2) =>
``