# Добавить класс при нажатии только одному элементу из группы схожих

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1D1B26;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff3000, #ed0200, #ff096c, #d50082);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: .8s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  background: #1D1B26;
}

.button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff3000, #ed0200, #ff096c, #d50082);
  transition: .8s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
}

.button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.button:hover:before {
  bottom: 0%;
  top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="filter1" value="red" class="button">1</button>
<button id="filter2" value="red" class="button">2</button>
<button id="filter3" value="red" class="button">3</button>
<button id="filter4" value="red" class="button">4</button>
```

Вопрос в том, как можно при нажатой кнопки сохранить её цвет, например, добавив к ней класс **.active**?

То есть, когда наводим на кнопку, она заполняется красным цветом если курсор убрали, то возвращается к первоначальному цвету, а если нажали на кнопку, то цвет должен зафиксироваться, как при наведении + если нажали на другую кнопку, то на первой цвет сбрасывается и фиксируется на нажатой.

Так же цвет нажатой кнопки не должен сбрасываться, если нажать на любое поле, например на блок.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626959/256824

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам поможет селектор `:focus`

```css
button {
  background-color: wheat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover, button:focus{
  background-color: teal;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Или можно использовать класс:

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
[].slice.call(btns).forEach(function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [].slice.call(btns).forEach(function(b1) {
      b1.classList[b1 === b ? 'add': 'remove']('active');
    });
  });
})
```

```css
button {
  background-color: wheat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover, .active{
  background-color: teal;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Comment: фокус сбрасывается, если нажать вне кнопки

Comment: тогда нужно навешивать класс..

Comment: как это можно реализовать у меня даже мыслей нет в какую сторону идти

Comment: @Grimm дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: Я прошу прощения. А есть ли возможность запустить это на IE 11? Везде работает кроме этого браузера

Comment: @Grimm проверяйте

Comment: Да, все работает.это очень круто. Спасибо!